# How to scale (enlarge) a legend in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I am using this [Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254536/122765) in my work. I am trying to add a legend to this code to annotate the graph. I found this code [Legend in Tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62262/legend-in-tikzpicture) So I have now the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\pgfdeclarelayer{signal}
\pgfsetlayers{signal,main}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  SBS/.style={code={
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
      \fill [pic actions/.try] (-1,0) -- (-1/2,3) -- (1/2, 3) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
      \fill [pic actions/.try] (-1/16,2) rectangle (1/16,4);
      \fill [pic actions/.try] (0,4) circle [radius=1/4];
      \foreach \i in {-1,1}
        \fill [shift=(90:4), xscale=\i]
          \foreach \r in {1,3/2,2}{
            (-45:\r) arc (-45:45:\r) -- (45:\r-1/10)
            arc(45:-45:\r-1/10) -- cycle
          };
       \end{scope}
  }},
  SU/.style={code={ 
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
      \fill [even odd rule, pic actions/.try] 
        (-1,-5/2) -- (-1,-1/8) -- (1,-1/8) -- (1,-5/2)
        arc (360:180:1 and 1/4) -- cycle
     (-1,5/2) -- (-1,1/8) -- (1,1/8) -- (1,5/2)
        arc (0:180:1 and 1/4) -- cycle
     (-3/4, 9/4) -- (-3/4, 3/8) -- (3/4, 3/8) -- (3/4, 9/4) 
     arc (0:180:3/4 and 1/8)-- cycle
     \foreach \i in {-1,0,1}{\foreach \j in {1,2,3}{
       (-\i*1/2-3/16,-\j/2-3/4) rectangle ++(3/8, 3/8)}}
     (-1/2,-3/4) rectangle (1/2, -1/4);
   \end{scope}
  }},
  SIGNAL/.style={code={
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
      \fill [pic actions/.try]
      (0,-3) -- (-1,1/2) -- (1/8,1/4) -- (0,3) -- (1,-1/2) -- (-1/8,-1/4)
      -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  }}
}

\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

%%--------------------------------
% definition to insert numbers
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node at (0.295,-0.0225){#1};
        },%
    },
}
\colorlet{sky blue}{blue!60!cyan!75!black}
\colorlet{dark blue}{blue!50!cyan}
\colorlet{chameleon}{olive!75!green}
\tikzset{signal/.style={draw=gray, line width=0.2em, dashed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em]

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=b1]
\pic [fill=sky blue] {SBS=p1};
\pic [rotate=15, fill=sky blue]  at (8,-4)  {SU=q1};
\pic [rotate=45, fill=sky blue] at (4,-2)  {SIGNAL=s1};
\node [line width=0.25em,draw=sky blue, shape=circle, fit={(p1) (q1) (s1)}] {};
\path (p1.north) node [below] {p1} (q1.north east) node [above] {q1};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(25,5)}, x=1em*7/8, y=1em*7/8, local bounding box=b2]
\pic [fill=chameleon] {SBS=p2};
\pic [fill=chameleon]  at (-8,0)  {SU=q2};
\pic [rotate=-75, fill=chameleon] at (-4,1)  {SIGNAL=s2};
\node [line width=0.25em,draw=chameleon, inner sep=1em,
  shape=circle, fit={(p2) (q2) (s2)}] {};
\path (p2.south) node [below] {p2} (q2.south) node [below] {q2};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(5,20)}, x=1em*5/8, y=1em*5/8, local bounding box=b3]
\pic [fill=violet] {SBS=p3};
\pic [fill=violet]  at (8,0)  {SU=q3};
\pic [rotate=-75, fill=violet] at (4,1)  {SIGNAL=s3};
\node [line width=0.25em,  draw=violet, inner sep=1em,
  shape=circle, fit={(p3) (q3) (s3)}] {};
\path (p3.north) node [above] {p3} (q3.south) node [below] {q3};
\end{scope}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{signal}
\draw [signal] 
  (p1) -- (q3) -- (p2) -- (q1) -- (p3) -- (q2) -- (p1) 
  (p1) -- (q1) (p2) -- (q2) (p3) -- (q3);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\node [regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, fit={(b1) (b2) (b3)},
draw=black, line width=0.25em, inner sep=-2em]
{};

\pic [fill=dark blue] at (-5, 10) {SBS};
\pic [fill=dark blue] at (25, 15) {SBS};
\pic [fill=dark blue] at (20, -8) {SU};

\begin{customlegend}[
      legend entries={ % <= in the following there are the entries
      Interference, 
      Strong Signal,
      Weak Signal
      },
      scale=4,
      % legend cell align={left},
      legend style={at={(-4,0)}}] % <= to define position and font legend
      % the following are the "images" and numbers in the legend
      \addlegendimage{-triangle 45,red,line width=0.3mm}
      \addlegendimage{-triangle 45,cyan,line width=0.3mm}
      \addlegendimage{-triangle 45,cyan,dashed,line width=0.3mm}
\end{customlegend}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that the legend is always small, I tried to add `nodes={scale=2}` which increased the text but not the arrows. I have also some emoticons in my legend which appear really small.

How can I make the legend large (including the text and the symbols and nodes and emoticons)?

Is there any better way to add a legend? Say I would like to add the phone to the legend how can I do this?

I have this result so far:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only offer a workaround as I do not understand macros like `pgfplots@init@cleared@structures` or `\csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname` well enough to dare playing with them. So I propose to draw the legend by hand.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\pgfdeclarelayer{signal}
\pgfdeclarelayer{legend back}
\pgfdeclarelayer{legend}
\pgfsetlayers{signal,main,legend back,legend}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  SBS/.style={code={
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
      \fill [pic actions/.try] (-1,0) -- (-1/2,3) -- (1/2, 3) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
      \fill [pic actions/.try] (-1/16,2) rectangle (1/16,4);
      \fill [pic actions/.try] (0,4) circle [radius=1/4];
      \foreach \i in {-1,1}
        \fill [shift=(90:4), xscale=\i]
          \foreach \r in {1,3/2,2}{
            (-45:\r) arc (-45:45:\r) -- (45:\r-1/10)
            arc(45:-45:\r-1/10) -- cycle
          };
       \end{scope}
  }},
  SU/.style={code={ 
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
      \fill [even odd rule, pic actions/.try] 
        (-1,-5/2) -- (-1,-1/8) -- (1,-1/8) -- (1,-5/2)
        arc (360:180:1 and 1/4) -- cycle
     (-1,5/2) -- (-1,1/8) -- (1,1/8) -- (1,5/2)
        arc (0:180:1 and 1/4) -- cycle
     (-3/4, 9/4) -- (-3/4, 3/8) -- (3/4, 3/8) -- (3/4, 9/4) 
     arc (0:180:3/4 and 1/8)-- cycle
     \foreach \i in {-1,0,1}{\foreach \j in {1,2,3}{
       (-\i*1/2-3/16,-\j/2-3/4) rectangle ++(3/8, 3/8)}}
     (-1/2,-3/4) rectangle (1/2, -1/4);
   \end{scope}
  }},
  SIGNAL/.style={code={
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
      \fill [pic actions/.try]
      (0,-3) -- (-1,1/2) -- (1/8,1/4) -- (0,3) -- (1,-1/2) -- (-1/8,-1/4)
      -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  }}
}


\colorlet{sky blue}{blue!60!cyan!75!black}
\colorlet{dark blue}{blue!50!cyan}
\colorlet{chameleon}{olive!75!green}
\tikzset{signal/.style={draw=gray, line width=0.2em, dashed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em]

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=b1]
\pic [fill=sky blue] {SBS=p1};
\pic [rotate=15, fill=sky blue]  at (8,-4)  {SU=q1};
\pic [rotate=45, fill=sky blue] at (4,-2)  {SIGNAL=s1};
\node [line width=0.25em,draw=sky blue, shape=circle, fit={(p1) (q1) (s1)}] {};
\path (p1.north) node [below] {p1} (q1.north east) node [above] {q1};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(25,5)}, x=1em*7/8, y=1em*7/8, local bounding box=b2]
\pic [fill=chameleon] {SBS=p2};
\pic [fill=chameleon]  at (-8,0)  {SU=q2};
\pic [rotate=-75, fill=chameleon] at (-4,1)  {SIGNAL=s2};
\node [line width=0.25em,draw=chameleon, inner sep=1em,
  shape=circle, fit={(p2) (q2) (s2)}] {};
\path (p2.south) node [below] {p2} (q2.south) node [below] {q2};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(5,20)}, x=1em*5/8, y=1em*5/8, local bounding box=b3]
\pic [fill=violet] {SBS=p3};
\pic [fill=violet]  at (8,0)  {SU=q3};
\pic [rotate=-75, fill=violet] at (4,1)  {SIGNAL=s3};
\node [line width=0.25em,  draw=violet, inner sep=1em,
  shape=circle, fit={(p3) (q3) (s3)}] {};
\path (p3.north) node [above] {p3} (q3.south) node [below] {q3};
\end{scope}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{signal}
\draw [signal] 
  (p1) -- (q3) -- (p2) -- (q1) -- (p3) -- (q2) -- (p1) 
  (p1) -- (q1) (p2) -- (q2) (p3) -- (q3);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\node [regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, fit={(b1) (b2) (b3)},
draw=black, line width=0.25em, inner sep=-2em]
{};

\pic [fill=dark blue] at (-5, 10) {SBS};
\pic [fill=dark blue] at (25, 15) {SBS};
\pic [fill=dark blue] at (20, -8) {SU};

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=legend,shift={(-8,0)},scale=3,transform shape]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{legend}
\pgfgettransformentries{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}
\coordinate (aux) at (-0.1,0);
\draw[-triangle 45,red,line width=\myscale*0.3mm] (0,0) -- ++ (1.6,0) 
node[right,black]{Interference};
\draw[-triangle 45,cyan,line width=\myscale*0.3mm] (0,-1) -- ++ (1.6,0) 
node[right,black]{Strong Signal};
\draw[-triangle 45,cyan,dashed,line width=\myscale*0.3mm] (0,-2) -- ++ (1.6,0) 
node[right,black]{Weak Signal};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{legend back}
\node[fit=(legend) (aux),fill=white,thick,draw,inner sep=2pt]{};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me remark that you are loading both `arrows` and `arrows.meta`, but only use `arrows`. Even though it does not really matter too much here, I'd recommend using `arrows.meta` instead.

Comment: Thank you. If I would like to add the phone `SU` for example to the legend, is it possible with `\pic [fill=black]  at (11,1)  {SU};`?

Comment: @Zir I would just add `\pic[scale=0.2] at (0.5,-3) {SU} (1.6,-3) node[right]{phone};` before the `\end{pgfonlayer}` of the legend scope. This code is set up in such a way that the legend box will just grow accordingly.